# difference between member function template of a template class and member function of a template class

Tags: c++, function, templates, member

**CODE 1 :**

```
template <class T>
class cat{
public:
       T a;
       void show(){
       cout << a ;
       }
};
```

**CODE 2 :**

```
template <class T>
class dog{
public:
       T a;
       template <class U> // making show function template
       void show(){
       cout << a ;
       }
};
```

so `cat::show()` is a member function of a template class.
and `dog::show()` is a member function template of a template class.

**Questions:** 
**1)** is there any difference between class template cat and dog, rather than when I call the member function show, I have to explicitly speciafy U for instance of dog template class? 
**2)** does the compiler handles them the same. for example cat::show() will not be compiled until I use it. and I guess the same thing for dog::show();. so is there anything Im missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

Those two are related only in the same way that the two free functions `foo` are related here:

```
void foo() {};
template <typename T>
void foo() {}
```

While being a member of a template class both will be instantiated on demand for implicit instantiations. On the other hand, if you explicitly instantiate the template class, the non-template function will be generated by the compiler, but the template member function will not.

Aside from that, the usual caveats: template functions will only match exact types, while non-template functions will allow implicit conversions:

```
template <typename T>
struct tmpl {
   void foo( T, T ) {}
   template <typename U>
   void bar( U, U ) {}
};
tmpl<int> t;
t.foo( 5, 1. );    // fine, will convert 1. from double to int
t.bar( 5, 1. );    // error
```

And all other differences between templated and not templated functions.

---

What I really don't understand is *why* this is confusing you so much. It seems that you are considering the *instantiation* as the only property of functions, which it is not. What is it that really bothers you? Why do you think a template and non-template functions would be the *same*?

In particular, I feel that you are wasting too much effort into a detail of implementation. In most cases, whether one or all member functions of a template class are instantiated does not really affect the semantics of your program, if your program *needs* the member function, then the compiler will generate code for it, if your program does not need it, there is no difference whether it generated the code or not (consider that the linker can remove any symbol, what is the difference of the member function never having been generated or it being removed by the linker?)

Comment: "but the template member function will not." I don't think that is true. The spec says that such members are instantiated too. It is just that many implementations (including modern ones like Clang) will not instantiate the member template definitions. That's a conforming deviation, because if the member template definition contained an error, the member template definition would be "ill-formed; no diagnostic required". For Clang, the reason they don't instantiate member template definitions is performance - they would need to typecheck a lot more then.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Can you point where in the standard it requires the template members of the template class to be instantiated? That makes no sense at all. What template argument should the template member function be instantiated for? `template <typename T> struct A { template <typename U> void f( U ) {} }; template class A<int>;` what types should `A<int>::f` be instantiated for? `A<int>::f<int>`, `A<int>::f<vector<map<pair<int,int>,double>>`?

Comment: you have provided `T = int`, so `A<int>` that was instantiated will get a function template definition where all references to `T` are replaced by `int`. Just like for any other member. The spec at 14.7.2p8 is pretty clear about this. For instance, this is "ill-formed; no diagnostic required": `template<typename T> struct A { template<typename U> void f(U) { T t; t.foo(); } }; template struct A<int>;`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I see what you say, I don't understand how this relates to my answer. I might not have phrased it correctly, the intent (let me try again) is to say that the compiler will not *generate code* for the templated member function. That is (almost) orthogonal with whether the template member function is well or ill formed: no code will be generated. Among other reasons (again, independently of whether the result is well or ill formed) because the compiler cannot possibly generate code for all potential instantiations of the template member function.

Comment: ... for all other (non-templated) members the compiler *knows* what the arguments to the template are: those of the class template, but for nested templates (whether functions or nested types) there is no such knowledge, the program can use those templates with *any* combination of arguments or none at all, so the compiler cannot possibly guess the types used, nor instantiate for all (since there are infinite types and we like our compilers to finish in a finite amount of time)

Comment: OK, that might have been the intent, but you do not mention anyting about generating code, but about generating functions and about not generating member function templates. You are saying *the non-template function will be generated by the compiler, but the template member function will not.*.

Comment: Also you are saying *so the compiler cannot possibly guess the types used, nor instantiate for all* -> No. *You provided `T`*. The compiler *knows* what the arguments are: those of the class template. There is no difference of the member template to the non-template members despite of the fact that the instantiation of the member template yields another template.

Comment: Perhaps you will better understand it when the explanation is not compressed into one of these comment boxes: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.clang.devel/22398/focus=22398